# User first_name and last_name limitations on Facebook and Twitter

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, twitter

I need to know the maximum length of users first and last name that he can have on Facebook and Twitter. Our application allows to register using this social networks and we have limitations for the number of characters in user's first and last names.
Too long names can spoil slicing.
Can anybody help?

Comment: Hi An6r, just to let you know that you can change your accepted answer if it better fits the intention of your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On twitter there's no `first_name` and `last_name`. However there is allocation to input **name** which is `20 Characters Max` 
You can update your twitter name (not username) via this

```
POST http://twitter.com/account/update_profile.json
```

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/post/account/update_profile

As for Facebook the maximum length for each field (that is first name and last name) is `75 Characters`

Comment: "As for Facebook the maximum length for each field (that is first name and last name) is 75 Characters"
Do you have a source for that?

Comment: @EdOrsi With no source, that was probably a guess. [Jeff has just posted today](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50223963/6225838) that the current limit is 30 chars found by reverse engineering, e.g. `123456789009876543211234567890`.

Answer (score 4):

On **Twitter**, your **username** can be up to **15** characters long and your **display name** can be up to **50** characters long. See [“How to Change Your Username”](https://help.twitter.com/en/managing-your-account/change-twitter-handle#definition:) in the Twitter Help Center. Those [seem](https://www.engadget.com/2017/11/10/twitter-expands-display-name-length/) to be the longest they’ve ever been allowed to be.

On **Facebook**, your first, middle, and last names can currently each be up to **30** characters long. Don’t know if that has always been the case so keep an eye out for older accounts that could have chosen longer names before the limits were set.

Facebook doesn’t mention character limits on names in their [“What names are allowed on Facebook?”](https://www.facebook.com/help/112146705538576) Help Center article nor in the [Graph API User](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user) documentation but I was able to reverse engineer the limits by trying to enter different lengths of names on the [“General Account Settings”](https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=account&section=name&view) page. Entering anything over 30 characters long gives you the “Names can’t have too many characters” error.

Comment: I was considering doing what you have just done, your effort is appreciated. Did you also figure out if the _name_ field maximum is the sum of the 3 names (i.e. **90** chars) in Facebook?

Comment: @CPHPython The max for the `name` Graph API User field seems to be **92** characters. I can't come up with a name that has 30 characters in each the first, middle, and last name that will pass the "Must be your authentic name" rule on the General Account Settings page but I was able to rename one of my [test users](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/test-users) to "Carlostopherichardavidaniielia Carlostopherichardavidaniielia Carlostopherichardavidaniielia" which puts the `name` field max at 92 characters (don't forget about the spaces).

Comment: Wow, nice one Jeff! Truly appreciated. I should be able to reupvote this again!